# Running selenium test cases(Test cases are in robot framework) using jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, robotframework

I have test cases which i have written in robot framework. I have written one library for robot framework but it all for selenium.  I am using firefox browser. This test cases are working fine if i am running through command line.
If I start test cases using jenkins this error will show. I am using shell command to start robot framework.

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Config Box"}
Stacktrace:
at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpkRQ7Lc/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///tmp/tmpkRQ7Lc/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10779)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpkRQ7Lc/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpkRQ7Lc/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpkRQ7Lc/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
```

Comment: For the purposes of debugging, if you put in a "sleep" keyword and wait for a few seconds before calling the keyword that is failing, does the test work? If so, the problem is simply that the browser is slower in your jenkins environment and the solution is to wait for elements to appear before trying to interact with them.

Answer (score 1):

When running tests with Jenkins there are different timings on when the elements are available. Try to use keywords of `Wait For ...` or `Sleep`.

Comment: wait or sleep is not helping me. Please let me know how to check available elements in that driver page? or how to print that page in html format. I am able to check title of page but not element.

Comment: You can use `Log Source`. See documentation at http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Log%20Source

Comment: driver.implicitly_wait(10) worked for me. Thanks for support.